# How can I send query parameters from SharePoint 2013 page to SharePoint App Web Part in autohosted app?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

As the title suggests, I have an AutoHosted SharePoint 2013 application. I have built a Web Part that can be added to a SharePoint page.

I want to be able to pass query parameters from the parent page to my sharepoint web part app.  I just can't seem to figure out how to listen for query parameters from my web part.

What I am trying to do:
mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mypage.aspx?variable=ContentIWant

I have a WebPart added to 'mypage.aspx' and I can't seem to be able to get the content from the 'variable'.

In C# on my app, I am outputting the following, but it does not output get parameters from the parent page.

```
foreach(string key in Request.Form.Keys ) {
     Response.Write ( Request.Form[key] );   
}

foreach(string key in Request.QueryString.Keys ) {
     Response.Write ( Request.QueryString[key] );
}
```

As you can see I am doing both POST and GET variables in the hope of finding something useful.

Has anyone ever tried to do what I am doing, and if so? Any advice or code samples?

Answer (score 0):

I have kind of the same problem.

You can see my current "hacky" javascript solution here: [Use Sharepoint querystring value as App-part property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656485/use-sharepoint-querystring-value-as-app-part-property)